# How can I correct "IntelliTrace code failed. The system cannot find the file specified."?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, intellitrace

Since some time after installing VS2015 (but not immediately after), whenever I debug in a particular large solution the message below is displayed. After clicking OK, debugging seems to progress normally.

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Cannot debug some of the code in process vstest.executionengine.exe [17608]. See below for status.

    IntelliTrace code failed. The system cannot find the file specified.
    Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code succeeded.

Click OK to continue debugging the remaining code. To disable debugging the failed type(s) of code in the future, change the corresponding setting in the project properties dialog.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

From it I gather that Intellitrace code failed and that I can disable debugging it in affected projects. My problem is that I'm not quite sure how to identify just what Intellitrace code is or what option I must use to disable debugging it. A way to identify the affected projects would be nice too, but if I must I can run through the properties of all projects, provided I know what option to look for.

I don't see anything written to the Output window that might provide some insight, could there be some other log that I'm not aware of?

I've spent a few hours searching the net but not found any insight. None of my colleagues are getting this, nor have any seen it before. Can anyone help?

For now I've disabled Intellitrace completely, which prevents the message from popping up but is not a solution if I actually want to start using Intellitrace features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by a fresh Windows install. It turned out that the package cache on my previous installation was badly corrupted and as it was Windows 8.1 I chose to do a fresh Windows 10 install.

Answer (score 3):

I work for the IntelliTrace team, so hopefully I can help you out. IntelliTrace is a features of Visual Studio Premium that automatically executes with the debugger when you debug managed code. It will give you additional information about your running program, such as a log of when exceptions occurred, calls to SQL, or ASP.NET, and many other useful events.

Given the nature of the error that you are seeing, it seems that the update did not install correctly, and that there is a binary missing. Have you attempted a repair on VS? This can be done via "Control Panel > Programs and Features > Microsoft Visual Studio 2015".

If that doesn't fix the problem, please follow up, and we'll try and fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I no longer have the problem though. Since experiencing the problem I have done a fresh Windows install on my my machine and am now using VS 2015 Professional, so don't have IntelliTrace anyway.